# How to navigate to correct error handling when creating a new model object in a different controller in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created two resources using rails generate scaffold called "trip" and "location". Because I needed the functionality of creating new locations related to a trip, I made a post request method in the trips controller which allows me to create new locations. I also created a view that is has identical form fields as the normal new locations form generated by rails.  However, when I enter invalid input in the location form, I get an error:

undefined method 'errors' for nil:NilClass
'.freeze; if trip.errors.any?

```
  </div>

  <% if trip.errors.any? %>
    <div style="color: red">
      <h2><%= pluralize(trip.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this trip from being saved:</h2>
```

Here is the form I provide in the custom view. This is where I send the post request to a custom endpoint "/create_location"

```
<h3>Create a new location</h3>
    <%= form_for @location, url: "/create_location" do |form| %>
      <div>
        <%= form.label :name, style: "display: block" %>
        <%= form.text_field :name %>
      </div>
```

This is my erb error handling. but the execution doesn't seem to get here for error handling

```
<% if @location.errors.any? %>
        <div style="color: red">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@location.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this @location from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @location.errors.each do |error| %>
              <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

How do I get the error to be handled using "location" errors?

Because I used the scaffold, I don't know exactly how errors are handled depending on what model I'm using.

Comment: When you get "undefined method 'errors' for nil:NilClass '.freeze; if trip.errors.any?" it's telling you that the variable `trip` is nil. So look at the code that is supposed to b e setting up that variable.